# configure network interface for wired and wireless connection

Tags: macos, shell, connection, wireless

I wanna write a script which can make Mac OS connect to wireless when wired connection is not available. And computer will connect to wired network automatically when the cable is connected. Could anyone give me some idea?

THX.

Answer (score 1):

I don't know if you need to be able to do this programmatically, but you can achieve the same effect by putting 'Ethernet' ahead of 'Wi-Fi' in the network settings service order.